# One-to-one delete for SQLAlchemy classes with inheritance

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have a class inheritance scheme as layed out in http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/inheritance.html#joined-table-inheritance

```
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, String, ForeignKey
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base


Base = declarative_base()


class Parent(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'parent'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    type = Column(String)

    __mapper_args__ = {'polymorphic_on': type}


class Child(Parent):
    __tablename__ = 'child'

    id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('parent.id'), primary_key=True)

    __mapper_args__ = {'polymorphic_identity': 'child'}
```

Having created an instance of `Child`, I'd like to be able to delete either the `Child` or the `Parent` reference without the other hanging around, but that's not what happens. When I fire up IPython...

```
In [1]: from stackoverflow.question import Parent, Child

In [2]: from sqlalchemy import create_engine

In [3]: from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker

In [4]: session = sessionmaker(bind=create_engine(...), autocommit=True)()

In [5]: with session.begin():
   ...:     session.add(Child())
   ...:     

In [6]: session.query(Parent).all()
Out[6]: [<stackoverflow.question.Child at 0x7fe408030240>]

In [7]: session.query(Parent).delete()
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IntegrityError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
/.../lib/python3.4/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py in _execute_context(self, dialect, constructor, statement, parameters, *args)
   1062                         parameters,
-> 1063                         context)
   1064         except Exception as e:

...
--> Big traceback here...
...

IntegrityError: (IntegrityError) update or delete on table "parent" violates foreign key constraint "child_id_fkey" on table "child"
DETAIL:  Key (id)=(1) is still referenced from table "child".
 'DELETE FROM parent' {}

In [8]: session.query(Child).delete()
Out[8]: 1

In [9]: session.query(Parent).all()
Out[9]: [<stackoverflow.question.Child at 0x7fe408030240>]
```

Deleting the `Parent` instance doesn't work, and deleting the `Child` instance leaves the `Parent` instance alive and well...

After experimenting a bit, setting the keyword argument `ondelete='CASCADE'` in the `ForeignKey` in `Child` allows me to delete the `Parent` (which cascades to the `Child`) but the reverse doesn't happen. Is there any way to configure these two classes so that deleting the `Child` also deletes the `Parent`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are confusing few things.

Lets leave the `inheritance` aside for a moment.

### 1. `session.query(MyTable).delete()`:

When you call `session.query(MyTable).delete()`, sqlalchemy will basically generate following SQL `DELETE FROM my_table`.
This means: **delete *all* entries from table `my_table`**

### 2. `session.delete(my_instance); ... session.commit()`

When you perform the following:

```
my_instance = session.query(MyTable).filter(MyTable.name == some_value).first()
session.delete(my_instance)  # !!!
# ...
session.commit()
```

sqlalchemy will generate following SQL: `DELETE FROM my_table WHERE id = ?`.
This means: **delete *a row* from table `my_table` for given `id`** (primary key)`.

> Good thing is that in this case sqlalchemy is smart enough to delete rows from multiple tables in case the joined inheritance is used.

### (Attempted) Answer

Now, the code you show is basically the first case. I do not think that you care about any references if you really want to delete *all* rows from some tables. But I really think that you want to simple remove just one instance (which might be few data rows from different tables). In this case, you should simply do the following:

```
# add a child
child = Child()
session.add(child)
session.commit()

# find the Child you want to delete by its primary key
child = session.query(Child).get(child_id)
# OR: find it by other filters
child = session.query(Child).filter(...).first()

# mark it for deletion
session.delete(child)
# SA will delete all properly
session.commit()
```

Comment: I think you got hung up on the specific way I formatted the code... I'll edit it to be clearer. My main concern is that doing things your way, there are still `Parent` objects kicking around.

Comment: Try it first, and then let me know if you still have this concern. In fact, pass `echo=True` to your engine creation and you will see generated `SQL` statements, which hopefully are enough to convince you the code works.

Comment: You're right. I didn't notice that you used `session.delete(child)` rather than something like `query(...).delete()`. Deleting the object from the session does what I want.

Comment: In my question I'm clearing the table because this issue came up in the `tearDown` methods of my unit tests, where I actually do want to clear the entire table of objects added during a test. In that case, I can just clear the `Parent` table. Thanks for clearing up my confusion!

Comment: You are welcome. Could you not do `engine.drop_all()` in the `tearDown` and `engine.create_all()` in the `setUp`?

Comment: I wanted to avoid the potential stumbling block of not importing all the model classes before calling `create_all`, but now that I think about it, it's seems like the better approach.